# C# Wpf Set Costum Style to ComboBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I've got a `ComboBox` bound to a List. The `ComboBox` has 3 ComboBoxItems from that list. I also got a `CheckBox`. If the `CheckBox` is unchecked and the first ComboBoxItem selected, the property "Property1" in my viewmodel is set to false. Now if "Property1" is false I'd like to change the Background and Foreground of this ComboBoxItem. How can I achieve this?

I was trying to get that done with Style and MultiDataTrigger but wasn't succesful - I only managed to change the Style for all of the ComboBoxItems and not specific one.

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
               <MultiDataTrigger>
                   <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedComboBoxItem}" Value="Item1" />
                       <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=CheckStatus}" Value="False" />
                   </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                   <Setter Property="Background" Value="GhostWhite" />
                   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gainsboro" />
               </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

How can I achieve to change the style of a specific ComboBoxItem when its bound via List?

Thanks for your hints / help.

Comment: post your code whatever you tried.

Comment: @tabby i added what i tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not the best solution, but a working one:

Instead of using a style, i created a combobox with an ItemTemplate

```
        <ComboBox Width="200" Height="30"  ItemsSource="{Binding SimpleList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Content="{Binding Name}" Background="{Binding BackGround}" Foreground="{Binding ForeGround}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

My SimpleList contains 3 "SimpleObjects" with Properties for Name, BackGround and ForeGround. BackGround is set to white and ForeGround to black by default.

Once my CheckBox is checked, I get the first Item of my List and change its properties.

```
    private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  SimpleObject obj = SimpleList.FirstOrDefault();
  obj.BackGround = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
  obj.ForeGround = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
}
```

Looking like this.
   [image: Looking like This]